# Type resolve fails for types with strange name (2.5.29.35)

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling, assembly-loading

I have a .NET app where I log failures to resolve types that are supposed to be loaded in the current domain. I have an event handler for `TypeResolve` that looks something like this:

```
Assembly TypeResolveFailed(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
   if (m_log != null)
   {
      m_log.DebugMessage($"TypeResolve failed for {args.Name} for AppDomain {AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName}");
   }

   return null;
}
```

I have started to see messages as the following:

```
TypeResolve failed for 2.5.29.35 for AppDomain myapp
TypeResolve failed for 2.5.29.17 for AppDomain myapp
TypeResolve failed for 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 for AppDomain myapp
TypeResolve failed for 2.5.29.35 for AppDomain myapp
TypeResolve failed for 2.5.29.32 for AppDomain myapp
```

What types are those having names such as `2.5.29.35` or `1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1`? I am not sure where this comes from in order to investigate it.

Comment: What names you expect them to have?

Comment: I wasn't aware `2.5.29.35` is a valid identifier name in C#. I don't know where this is coming from, so I expect nothing particular.